# Date_Format and sort by date

Tags: mysql

I am currently experiencing a problem with sorting a result by a data column which is using date_format.

I have the below dates:

- 12-03-12
- 21-03-12
- 25-03-12
- 17-04-12

When I perform the query:

```
SELECT date FROM myTable ORDER date DESC
```

The dates are ordered in the correct order

- 17-04-12
- 25-03-12
- 21-03-12
- 12-03-12

When I perform the query

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y') as `date` ORDER BY date
```

The dates are now in the wrong order

- 25-03-12
- 21-03-12
- 17-04-12
- 17-03-12
- 14-03-12

I've also tried running the query
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y') as `date` ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y') but has made no difference.

How can I get this to sort in the correct order.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that you are overriding the column name with the alias.

Choose another alias:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%d-%m-%Y') as date_formatted
FROM myTable 
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this but its still not working. It looks as if its only sorting by the first part of the date, i.e. the day, its not taking the month into consideration

Comment: @Boardy: No, you are not doing exactly this. You are either having more columns or something is different in your query.

Comment: sorry I was being a numpty i misread your code. I was saying order by date_formatted instead of date. it works fine now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

Just specify table name for the column in `ORDER BY` clause:

```
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y') as `date`
    FROM myTable
ORDER BY myTable.`date` DESC -- <<<<<<
```

In this case mysql knows you want to sort by table column, not by the expression you've evaluated in the `SELECT` part

Comment: yes, that's it! especially when I do not want to change date key, just want it to be formatted by db